# eof bit : before or after a read failure?

Tags: c++, io, stream, ifstream, eof

I currently write a class for some IO operations. Some functions return whether the IO operation was successful. If I'm reading a file, I wonder if I should return `std::ifstream::good()` or `!std::ifstream::fail()` to indicate whether the IO operation was sucessful.

The difference comes from the `eof` bit and I'm not sure that I correctly understand it.

Suppose that I have a binary file with 4 bytes in it (1 integer).

Suppose that I read this integer.

My question is : will the `eof` flag be set after this operation or after the next IO operation (that will fail) ?

If it set directly after this operation, if my reading function return `std::ifstream::good()`, then the result will be `false` (but the integer was correctly read).

Can you explain me when the eof bit is set and what should I return at the end of my functions ?

Comment: Rather than implementing your own `istream`-like object, consider deriving from `std::streambuf` and wrapping that in an actual `istream` via its `rdbuf()` function. You only need to implement a few functions of `streambuf` and get all the bells and whistles of `istream` for free. (Not sure if this helps in your situation!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The EOF flag is set *after* you attempt to read over the end of the stream.

Your function should return a reference to the original stream, and you should use it in a loop or in a conditional, like this:

```
std::istream & process(std::istream & is)
{
    int n;
    if (is >> n) { std::cout << "Read one int: " << n << "\n"; }
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstread infile("data.bin");

    while (process(infile)) { }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The "eof" bit of a stream is set when a read operation attempts to read beyond the end of the stream. The read operation that reads beyond the end of the stream may or may not be successful. This is independent of whether the "eof" bit is set.

For this reason you should always check the result of the read operation itself and not check the state of the stream flags after a read.

For an example of all four combinations:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>

int main()
{
        int n;
        if (std::cin >> n)
                std::cout << "read an int with value = " << n << '\n';
        else
                std::cout << "read of int failed\n";

        std::cout << "cin.eof() = " << std::cin.eof() << '\n';
        return 0;
}
```

Successful read that sets the eof bit:

```
$ printf 1 | ./a.out
read an int with value = 1
cin.eof() = 1
```

Successful read that does not set the eof bit:

```
$ echo 1 | ./a.out
read an int with value = 1
cin.eof() = 0
```

Unsuccesful read that does not set the eof bit:

```
$ printf abc | ./a.out
read of int failed
cin.eof() = 0
```

Unsuccesful read that sets the eof bit:

```
$ echo | ./a.out
read of int failed
cin.eof() = 1
```

Comment: I don't understand why the first example sets the eof bit and not the second one. Can you explain me why ?

Comment: @Vincent: In the first example the stream consists only of the character `1`. In order to test whether the integer being read is `1`, `10` or `123456789` another character read (or peek) must be attempted but as there are no more characters this sets the eof bit. In the second example `1` is followed by a newline. The read attempt after reading the `1` reads a non-digit (the newline) so the number read finished at `1`. As the end of the stream wasn't read past the eof bit is not set.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you very much ! But as I am dealing with binary files, I do not need to check the next character.

Comment: @Vincent: A binary file could mean a file in any format. Only you know what constitutes a successful read or not. If you need to read four bytes (characters) to make a valid read then you need to test (at a minimum) whether (e.g.) a four byte `read(char*, std::streamsize)` or equivalent call succeeds. Again, test the result of the read and not the flags on the stream. (Also, you might be doing some optimistic reading, e.g. trying to read 16 bytes, if the call only reads 8 bytes you might still have two out of four successful reads even thought the eof bit is already set.)

Answer (score 0):

The eof flag be set 'after the next IO operation(that will fail)'. You should return `std::ifstream::good()` after the read operation which tells whether any error flags were set.